# Compare datetimes, see if one hour has passed

Tags: c#, datetime, compare

I am trying to see if one hour has passed since the creation of a token object.
i am using datetime.utcnow when creating it.

I have tried datetime.compare, and straight up comparing two date times, but it gets the same result no matter what i do.. (not what i want)

If one hour since its creation has passed, the Token should be "consumed", so it is no longer valid.

**Token object**

```
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public int UserId { get; set; }

    public string Token { get; set; }

    public System.DateTime Time_stamp { get; set; }

    public Nullable<bool> Consumed { get; set; }
```

**My validation method**

```
public bool IsValidToken(string token)
{
        var tokenEntity = this.GetAll().Where(x => x.Consumed == false && x.Token == token).FirstOrDefault();

            if (tokenEntity != null)
            {
                var tokenDate = tokenEntity.Time_stamp;

                var machineDate = DateTime.UtcNow;


                var result = DateTime.Compare(tokenDate, machineDate.AddHours(1));

                if (result > 0)
                {
                    tokenEntity.Consumed = true;
                    this.Update(tokenEntity);
                    return false;
                }
                else
                {
                    return true;
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
```

Comment: Why do you compare to utcnow + 1hour? Don't you actually want to know if `machineDate - tokenDate` is greater than 1 hour? like `if ((machineDate - tokenDate).TotalHours > 1)`?

Comment: The issue is you're adding one hour to the machine date when comparing dates. Any date in the past or current is going to return < 0. Try `var result = DateTime.Compare(tokenDate, machineDate.AddHours(-1));` instead.

Comment: In my defense... it is friday here... so i quess my brain is ready for the weekend...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Instead of `DateTime.Compare()` you can subtract two `DateTime` and get total hours of resultant `DateTime`.

Something like,

```
var result = (DateTime.UtcNow - tokenEntity.Time_stamp).TotalHours;
if(result > 1)
{
   //Do your business logic for expiring token
}
else
   //Your business logic
```

[Try it online](https://dotnetfiddle.net/O3KPW9)

Comment: Need to restore a db before i can try this solution.. but is almost 100% certain this is it... Will mark it as answer right after testing.

Comment: @andrelange91, Take your time. I also added online fiddle which supports my answer.

Comment: Also, if you only want to know if the two `DateTime` values are `1` hour apart, but don't care which one is less than the other, you can use the `Duration()` method to get the absolute value of the difference. Otherwise the difference may be a negative number (which would fail the `result > 1` test in cases where it shouldn't). For example: `(DateTime.UtcNow - tokenEntity.Time_stamp).Duration().TotalHours;`

Comment: @RufusL, yes you are correct. Use of `Duration()` will give us absolute value. result will store negative value only if `Time_stamp` is greate than `UtcNow` by 1 hours. Now question to OP is does `Time_stamp` contains value greater than `DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(+1)`?

Comment: @PrasadTelkikar I had to add Duration() on the end, but now it works. Thank you for the help

Answer (score 4):

> *"I am trying to see if [more than] one hour has passed since the creation of a token object"*

The problem appears to be that you are *adding* an hour to the current time instead of *subtracting* an hour. You can subtract an hour by passing `-1` to the `AddHours` method.

Then there's also an issue that the arguments are in an incorrect order when calling `Compare`, because the `Compare` method will return `1` if the first argument is greater than the second. Since we want to know if the value of "one hour ago" is greater than the token creation time, we should pass that value first when calling `Compare`:

```
var result = DateTime.Compare(machineDate.AddHours(-1), tokenDate);
```

---

Another (preferable) option is to simply use the `>` operator, and write the code in a way that resembles the way you would write it in English. Another way to say *"I am trying to see if [more than] one hour has passed since the creation of a token object"* is:

> *"Is the current time more than the sum of the token creation time plus one hour"*

Which could be written as:

```
if (machineDate > tokenDate.AddHours(1))
```

Comment: Your last approach to check token expiration time is elegant and clear.

Answer (score 3):

```
// Add -1 hour to simulate timespan being one hour in past
DateTime d1 = DateTime.Now.AddHours(-1);
DateTime d2 = DateTime.Now;
TimeSpan diff = d2 - d1;
bool diffIsGreaterThan1Hour = diff.TotalHours > 1;
```